# How to implement security in spring boot if we use scopes with attributes

Tags: s4sdk

I use scopes with attributes as described [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4505d0bdaf4948449b7f7379d24d0f0d/2.0.02/en-US/3bfb120045694e21bfadb1344a693d1f.html). 
Do you know how to implement the security configuration in a spring boot app to achieve that only the corresponding data regarding the scope attribute will be served.

Comment: Hi Jürgen, can you please clarify what you mean by "corresponding data". Do you mean from a database?. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, i mean from database. I want to implement a Restservice to read some data from database and here I want to service only suitable data corresponding to the attribute in scope.

Comment: Have you tried using the attributes that can be modelled in the security descriptor of XSUAA. This way you can reference additional attributes from your role template which then should appear when creating/assigning the roles. For example, you may model a key "Country" and then supply the country when assigning the role to the respective user. In the code, you then may public String[] getAttribute(String attributeName) throws XSUserInfoException; from the XS2 sec libraries and pass it to your database queries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try this.

Comment: Hello Jürgen, if your question is answered, please "accept" the answer given by Philipp by clicking the green checkmark. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two approaches you can use to accomplish this result depending on your concrete requirements. However, first of all there is no such thing like a parametrized scope with XSUAA.

1. It is possible to model additional attributes into the role templates of XSUAA, for example, a `Country` attribute like this in `xs-security.json`

```js
  "attributes": [ 
  { 
    "name" : "Country", 
    "description" : "Country parameter for the Role", 
    "valueType" : "string" 
  }],
  "role-templates": [
  {
    "name": "BusinessPartnerViewer",
    "description": "Role to view business addresses",
      "scope-references" : [
        "$XSAPPNAME.ViewAddresses"
      ],
      "attribute-references": [
        "Country"
      ]
  }
```

Then you need to recreate your XSUAA instance in CloudFoundry with `cf create-service xsuaa application <serviceinstance> -c xs-security.json`. Note: You cannot update the binding when you had other role template definitions previously.

Based on this, a subscriber of the application may instantiate roles at runtime providing an attribute along with the OAuth scope.

This approach has the downside that the consumer of the application may have to create many roles depending on the possible permutations of scopes and attributes.

2. Of course, you can always consider implementing your own approach, if the first approach is not sufficient. In this case, your application has to model and resolve the dependencies yourself depending on the user context, i.e., you have to create a database table that maps users to scopes and/or additional attributes and then you lookup at runtime the properties based on the information from the Json Web Token.